# How to convert date format to another format without making it string?

Tags: date, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a form and when inserting the data the date is inserted in the database in this format :

`2017-04-01 00:00:00.0`

Here is the component for inserting date into database

```
                            <p:outputLabel for="dateFin" value="Date fin"/>
                        <p:calendar id="dateFin" value="#{etpBean.dateFin}"  required="true">
                        </p:calendar>
```

here is my component

```
                        <p:outputLabel for="dateDebut" value="Date Debut"/>
                    <p:calendar id="dateDebut" value="#{etpBean.dateDebut}" required="true">
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{etpBean.onDateDebutChange}"/>
                    </p:calendar>
```

And in this form for search by date and is the same component, then When i chose the date to do the search by date and i display it in my bean it is in this format

`Sun Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT 2017`

So the list that I recover from the database and always empty since it is not the same format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are a little bit confused. The date does not change just its appearance. The `<p:calendar>` has its (maybe local dependent) format and it should differ from the one applied when you visualize it in another view. The visual format of the `TTimeStemp` values may be set by `<f:convertDateTime>` subtags:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</h:inputText>

<p:calendar value="#{bean.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</p:calendar>
```